# Benefits of SPATIAL over using standard bounding box query

Tags: mysql, spatial, bounds, bounding-box

## Benefits of SPATIAL over BOUNDING

What are the benefits of using a SPATIAL query rather than a simple MySQL query that utilised a bounding box?

For example, if I wanted to find all locations that fall within a certain polygon:

Something like this:

### Bounding Box Example

```
SELECT * FROM geoplaces 
WHERE geolat BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND geolng BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

As I understand, the only real benefit is that spatial will also factor in the earth's curvature?

Which method is fastest also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Advantages:

1. You can use shapes other than points
   and rectangles, and operations other
   than "is-in".
2. If you can use SPATIAL
   indexes, performance is orders of
   magnitude better (depending of
   course on the size and nature of
   your data).

Disadvantages:

1. Spatial objects are binary blobs - some care is needed handling them (e.g. you typically can't copy-paste a value).
2. Spatial indexes in mySQL are only available for MyISAM tables.
3. Support in mySQL is somewhat primitive; many operations are not implemented yet

If your database is large and you need searches like the one in your example to be fast, you should definitely go with SPATIAL indexes.

Comment: I think I read that 5.0.3+ mysql introduced Spatial for Innodb tables also. Thanks for your response.

Comment: As far as I could tell when using them, it's all plain old Pythagorean planar geometry, not really spherical geometry.Definitely useable without math skills, although some computing/programming experience will be necessary.